# customize list view page of app

Tags: list-view, app

we have to **add** some elements to a list view of an sharepoint 2013 app.

We've found [this example on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524962/JSLink-Custom-JS-Rendering-in-SharePoint) as well as on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj220045(v=office.15).aspx) but the given code overrides the complete view structure.

How to add just a button or a hyperlink above the given allitems.aspx without loosing the view of the columns?
How to change schema.xml so that we can deploy the app with the new design?

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSR function. You can insert a script in the view, the steps are:

1. Go in the view you want to edit.
2. Click "Settings" which is next to the user name in the upper right corner.
3. Click "Edit Page".

In this part you can already edit many things.

4. In this part you can already edit many things.
5. To insert a script in the view click "Edit Web Part" which is on the web part of your display.
6. In the right menu you click "Miscellaneous".
7. You will see a field called "Link JS," you insert the link that is your script.

Remember that you can only insert only one script, if you want to add more jquery, copy and paste the code to your jquery script.

I am available to help you.

Comment: thanks, but we'd prefer to handle it before we deploy the solution so it's out of use to edit the view. Apart from that it is an app so you can't call settings & edit page => youwould have to manage that through Manipulation of URL by toolpaneview Parameter